# Set default value in Tag helper .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have `dropdown` list in my page , which uses an `enum` list to bind.

My `enum` looks like

```
  public enum PaymentType
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The Cash
        /// </summary>
        Cash = 0,

        /// <summary>
        /// The Credit
        /// </summary>
        Credit = 1,

        /// <summary>
        /// The Debit
        /// </summary>
        Debit = 2
    }
```

And I am binding this enum to the dropdown like below

```
   <select class="select-text" id="paymentType"  asp-
for="PurchaseOrder.PaymentType" required asp-items="@(new 
SelectList(Model.PaymentTypes, "Id", "Name"))">

<option selected="selected" value ="">--Select payment type--</option>
   </select>
```

The issue is like `PurchaseOrder.PaymentType` is an integer filed so here the default value is coming as `0` and this makes my `dropdown` always selected to `Cash`. I know making `PurchaseOrder.PaymentType` nullable is an option but I want the filed as non nullable.

I have tired to add `value=""` in the select also tried `selected="selected"` in the default option , but nothing is working.

Can someone help me to solve this issue with tag helper syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a "blank" option, then your purchase order's `PaymentType` property should be nullable. You can use the `[Required]` attribute on it to enforce that the user must actually submit a value.

If you cannot do that because you're working with your entity class directly, then stop doing that. Always use view models all the time.

Comment: good point , will do that. let me make it nullable and use required attribute. I am not working with entity class directly

Answer (score 1):

You need the [SelectList(IEnumerable, String, String, Object, String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.selectlist.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Rendering_SelectList__ctor_System_Collections_IEnumerable_System_String_System_String_System_Object_) overload.

> Initializes a new instance of the SelectList class by using the
>   specified items for the list, the data value field, the data text
>   field, a selected value, and the data group field.

e.g. in your code:

```
SelectList(Model.PaymentTypes, "Id", "Name", 1)
```

Comment: can your provide an example?

Comment: thanks for helping . Used the solution proposed by Chris Pratt